# Why doesn't this extension of the JavaScript object work?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I must have some misunderstanding of objects and the prototype pattern in JavaScript, but I can not understand why the following code does not work:

```
Object.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log(this);
  return this;
}

var test = { 'foo' : 'bar'};
test.log();
```

Why does this throw an `object has no method 'log'` error?

Comment: what browser? it works for me in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/rcG2R/

Comment: Also works in IE7, could you tell us something else about your environment?

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe the order in which you're adding 'log' to the object prototype and actually calling it is backwards.  Make sure that you're adding the log method before calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work according to spec. I pasted your code as is into IE10 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

try logging a value inside the log function:

Object.prototype.log = function(){console.log(this.foo);};